# Where to find google-api-services-youtube jar file

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am at my wit's end and this should not be so difficult. Youtube v2 APIs are deprecated rendering my application useless. So, based on this website (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java#search_by_keyword), I am trying to run the sample. I downloaded google v3 client libraries from this location (https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/). Now in the code sample there are multiple imports for com.google.api.services.*. But this jar is not included in the client libraries and I have spent more than 2 hours to figure out where to get this jar. I am going around circular references not finding anything. Is there some obvious stuff that I am missing. I am not familiar with maven, so if it is straightforward maven stuff, please just point me to the google site where I can download latest jar.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found it at http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/maven2/com/google/apis/google-api-services-youtube/v3-rev136-1.20.0/.

Though it solved my problem for now, can someone explain me the rationale behind having jars in such hidden locations. I am not full time into jave for the past few years, so I am not sure if I missed anything.

Comment: That's just a maven mirror ... and any of the maven mirrors would have it. This does seems esoteric, but it's not the official way to get it. I believe the URL where you downloaded the client is an obsolete one; the java client moved to GitHub a while ago and can now be found at https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client. More importantly, the docs for the youtube specific functions of the api client (https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/youtube/v3) detail how to get the jar you need via download, via Maven, or via Gradle.

Comment: @jlmcdonald Thank you for your reply. This makes it a little clear. Since youtube stopped supporting v2 very recently, my website stopped working and I was forced to look at v3 API. I got these jars and resurrected the main functionality but will look into above for getting latest version. The URL you gave (https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/youtube/v3) has three links on bottom, maven, gradle and direct download link. I downloaded from the direct link and it was missing the other jar. I am not sure why developers are forced to pick maven or gradle !!

Answer (score 0):

Go to this [maven central repository link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis/google-api-services-youtube).

You can either download the jar directly or get maven/gradle dependency.

> You can get all the google libraries in the [maven central repository's google group](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.apis)

**Note**:  Always use a build system, it will make your job easy. You don't need to manually download the file, extract to the right folder blah,blah,blah... Just include the dependency in the `maven/gradle` file and it will take care of the rest